# Video.js: how to find out if the current device has native playback before initializing?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video, video.js

Is there a way to find out if the currently used device will be playing on native controls with video.js **before** initializing the player?

I am working on a lightbox solution which should be just playing the video natively on iOS and Android if the current browser does support it. Didn't find any API hook or event for this.

Currently working with video.js v5.0.0-rc63.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only need to check if the video player uses its own `controls`, you can just check for your video element's `controls` attribute :

```
if(document.querySelector('video').controls){
    // native
}else{
    // videojs fallback
}
```

Comment: Wow. That was easy. Thanks for the hint!

Answer (score 0):

I have worked on video players. iOS not allow to use the physical controlls by external libraries (by code).  but if you want to retrict or allow some device here is some piece of code (jQuery) by that you can check what type of device it is ..

```
if( /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
// some code..
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That sadly doesn't answer the question. I know how to get a mobile device - but there are some which won't be playing with native controls (like Chrome on Android). So I'm actually searching for a way to determine if native playback is going to happen or not.

Comment: @mvmoay: for that you have to make an hard coded check after checking

Comment: Yes, I guess I will have to. But how? Is there a function in videojs that could tell me about the playback behaviour of the device?

Comment: for that you have to develop a function that will be called on load that will check the device. I know this is crazy but in my knowledge you have to develop by your own. :)